# Why bandits are not dead from poison?

Tags: kingdom-come-deliverance

I decided to try cloak and dagger stuff in this game. There is a small bandit camp with 3 bandits just north of Ledetchko at the forest border.

"Great" - I thought - "I'll poison their cooking pot with Bane potion and loot stuff from their cold hands".

The last guy went to bed around 10:20 PM. I sneaked in right after that and put 2 bottles of bane into their cooking pot. Then I speed-waited till 6 AM since wiki says it's 7 AM when they have their breakfast.

I waited till 11 AM in real time (no speed-waiting) nearby behind a bush to see them dead, but when I approached them - they were quite alive! And they murdered me. While wiki says it takes only 50 seconds to kill main character when Bane-poisoned.

And I did several attempts. And every time they were alive. Not a single of them were cold on the ground. I also tried to steal their stuff from their trunk while they were asleep, but they were waking up in the process every time even when I opened chest (in a single attempt, mind you).

So in the end I murdered them naked with my sword when they agroed me at the last steal attempt.

But I still can't understand why they were alive every time when they should be dead from poisoning and how they hear me opening their trunk when I have zero noise (because of my choise of clothing) and opened it at my first attempt?

Could you explain, please?

Comment: I think opening a trunk simply makes noise. In any case, it is completely independent of the amount of sound your outfit makes. As for your question: have you tried the same things in other camps? Maybe there is something weird going on with those specific NPCs. Unlikely, but worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

This may sound obvious, but did you see the enemies eat from the poisoned pot? From what I remember (I haven’t play for a while), most bandits in camp eat (at least) when they wake up at dawn (05:00, IIRC).

Once they start eating, death will follow in a few (tens of) seconds, maybe even before they’re finished eating!
The other awake enemies will freak out ("A corpse!!"), but will eventually calm down… and resume eating, dying one by one, without anyone thinking about food poisoning for a single moment. :P